# Call Google Contact API v3.0 using client library

Tags: c#, google-api, dotnetopenauth

I need to call **Google Contact API v3.0** with DotNetOpenAuth(or any client libraray),but i am not finding any help,can someone guide me?

Is it necessary to use `OAUTH 2.0` to call Google Contact API v3.0?or it can be done by `OAUTH 1.0`?

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out by adding header `request.Headers.Add("GData-Version", "3.0");` before making request to Google Conatact API